# Find probability between $-\infty$ and $0$ of ExGaussian Distribution?

Tags: probability, density-function, skewness, kurtosis

The graph shown below is the numerically result of differences of Normal Distribution ($N(15.5 , 0.60^2))$ and Exponential Distribution $(\exp(0.5))$ (Both are independent).

I am trying to find the pdf of this function[image: negative skew].
............
where the result of difference of both distribution with  mean ${} = 15$, std ${} = 2$, skewness ${}= -1.7$, and kurtosis ${}= 7.3$.

What is the probability between $-\infty$ to $0$?

Comment: I think you mean CDF? Anyway, you cannot determine that without first assuming a distribution. Or estimating an empirical probability directly from the data. From the plot it looks like it's zero or close to it. Is this a positive only distribution?

Comment: (1) You appear to supply a summary of *data* rather than a function.  (2) You graph provides no information whatsoever about values less than zero, so we must suppose you don't really mean to ask about the "probability between $-\infty$ and $0$"--but what is your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The distribution is that of the negative of an ExGaussian random variable (or [exponentially-modified Gaussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentially_modified_Gaussian_distribution)).

The ExGaussian is the distribution of the sum of an exponential and a Gaussian (normal) random variable (independent of each other). If $X_0\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and $Y\sim \text{Exp}(\lambda)$ (under the rate parameterization) then $Z_0=X_0+Y$ is $\text{ExGaussian}(\mu,\sigma^2,\lambda)$.

Note that $Z_1=-Z_0 = -X_0-Y=X_1-Y$ is the difference between $X_1$ (a normal r.v. with mean the negative of the mean of $X_0$ and the same variance) and $Y$ (an exponential with rate parameter $\lambda$).

You don't say whether your exponential parameter is a rate or a scale parameter, but you have $\lambda=0.5$ in the first case and $2$ in the second case.

So for your parameters $P(X_1-Y<0)=P(X_0+Y>0)=1-F(x=0;\mu=-15.5,\sigma^2=0.6^2,\lambda)$ where $F$ is the cdf given at the Wikipedia page linked above; that is (using the notation there with a slight improvement):

$F=\Phi (u;0,v)-e^{-u+v^{2}/2+\log(\Phi (u;v^{2},v))}$, where
$u=\lambda (x-\mu),\, v=\lambda\sigma$ and $\Phi (x;\mu ,\sigma )=\Phi(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})$ with $\Phi$ the standard normal cdf.

Similarly the pdf is given as $ {\frac {\lambda }{2}}e^{{\frac {\lambda }{2}}(2\mu +\lambda \sigma ^{2}-2x)}\operatorname {erfc} \left({\frac {\mu +\lambda \sigma ^{2}-x}{{\sqrt {2}}\sigma }}\right)$; if you negate both $x$ and $\mu$ you should get the density of your variable.

Note that $\text{erfc}(x)={\frac {2}{\sqrt {\pi }}}\int _{x}^{\infty }e^{-t^{2}}\,dt$; this can be rewritten in terms of $\Phi$ if required. If I have done that correctly I think it should be

$f(x;\mu,\sigma^2,\lambda)=\frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(\frac{\lambda^2\sigma^2}{2}-\lambda(x-\mu))\cdot\Phi(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}-\lambda\sigma)$